# next page crawl in Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to get some data from the website but my spider is not crawling to the next page even after a proper pagination link.

```
import scrapy


class NspiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "nspider"
    allowed_domains = ["elimelechlab.yale.edu/"]
    start_urls = ["https://elimelechlab.yale.edu/pub"]

    def parse(self, response):
        title = response.xpath(
            '//*[@class="views-field views-field-title"]/span/text()'
        ).extract()
        doi_link = response.xpath(
            '//*[@class="views-field views-field-field-doi-link"]//a[1]/@href'
        ).extract()

        yield {"paper_title": title, "doi_link": doi_link}

        next_page = response.xpath(
            '//*[@title="Go to next page"]/@href'
        ).extract_first()  # extracting next page link

        if next_page:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=response.urljoin(next_page), callback=self.parse)
```

PS: I don't want to use LinkExtractor.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing wrong with your next_page logic, code is just not reaching this because the yield for the item is in the same identation level. Try the following approach:

```
import scrapy


class NspiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "nspider"
    allowed_domains = ["elimelechlab.yale.edu"]
    start_urls = ["https://elimelechlab.yale.edu/pub"]

    def parse(self, response):
        for view in response.css('div.views-row'):
            yield {
                'paper_title': view.css('div.views-field-title span.field-content::text').get(),
                'doi_link': view.css('div.views-field-field-doi-link div.field-content a::attr(href)').get()
            }

        next_page = response.xpath(
            '//*[@title="Go to next page"]/@href'
        ).extract_first()  # extracting next page link

        if next_page:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=response.urljoin(next_page), callback=self.parse)
```

Comment: thanks for this, but "doi_link" is returning None for every element. Can you look at the CSS selector, I only know the XPath selector so not able to figure out what is wrong?

Comment: @loving_guy small typo on css selector, just fixed it,please try again and let me know if it works :)